# JPA: NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'myPU' is defined

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-bean

I'm converting our webapp from an XML-based IoC, straight Hibernate webapp to one using annotations and JPA 2.1. Our app server is WebLogic 12.1.3, we're using Spring 3.2.13 and Hibernate 4.3.9. Our architecture is layered, with each layer ending up in its own JAR file. The layout of the EAR file is as follows:

```
|-EAR
   |-- my-app.ear
   |-- my-app.war
   |-- lib
        |-- my-web.jar
        |-- my-services.jar
        |-- my-jpa.jar
        |   |-- META-INF
        |       |-- persistence.xml
        |-- someotherlib.jar
```

At the top of the IoC chain is our DelegateFactory, which is used by Struts1 actions (we'll upgrade that later).

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.mycompany.myapp.dao.jpa"})
public class DelegateFactory
{
  public static DelegateFactory getInstance()
  {
    if (singleton == null)
    {
      AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();

      ctx.register(DelegateFactory.class);
      ctx.refresh();

      singleton = ctx.getBean(DelegateFactory.class);

      ctx.close();
    }
    return singleton;
  }
}
```

The IoC works when finding the web, service and DAO beans, but fails when trying to find the persistence unit. Below is the base class for our JPA DAOs. It is a plain DAO, not a Spring DAO. In an effort to make it work, I tried having both the em and the emf be injected.

```
public abstract class AbstractMyProjectJpaDao extends AbstractJpaTypedDao
{
  public static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "myPU";

  @PersistenceUnit(unitName = PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME, name = PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME)
  @Override
  public void setEntityManagerFactory(
    EntityManagerFactory emf)
  {
    super.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
  }

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME, name = PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME, type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
  @Override
  public void setEm(
    EntityManager em)
  {
    super.setEm(em);
  }
}
```

The only XML file we seem to need so far is the persistence.xml file, which is below.

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/myDS</jta-data-source>
    (declaration of persistent entities here)
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here's the failure:

```
Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'myPU' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:575)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1111)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.findEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:110)
```

My guess is that it just can't find the persistence.xml file, but according to what I've read, it's in a valid location.

What am I missing?

Comment: Same problem when copying persistence.xml to my-app.war/WEB-INF/classes

Comment: Didn't work when I tried 

  @PersistenceUnit(unitName="lib/my-jpa.jar#myPU",name="myPU")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of the problem is that I was not inserting the EntityManagerFactory. I ended up creating a dao-beans.xml file with this:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPU" />
</bean>
```

Then I had to add the @ImportResource annotation to my DelegateFactory so that the XML file could be found.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.mycompany.myapp.dao.jpa"})
@ImportResource("classpath:dao-beans.xml")
public class DelegateFactory
{
...
}
```

I also had to change the JNDI name of my data source in persistence.xml from "java:/jdbc/myDS" to just "jdbc/myDS". I think that's a WebLogic thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a PersistenceConfiguration. the `repo.package` points to any repository location you maybe using such as Springs CRUD/JPA repository. The `entity.package` points to the package your JPA DAO's reside.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = {"repo.package"},
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager"
)
public class PersistenceConfiguration {

  public static final HashSet<String> cacheNames = new HashSet<>();

  private static final String[] PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = {"entities.package"};

  private static final Properties hibernateProperties;
  static {
    hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior", "convertToNull");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dbcp.maxActive", "50");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle", "10");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dbcp.maxWait", "5000");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size property", "50");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.charSet", "UTF-8");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", "true");
  }

   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource(){
      DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
      dataSource.setDriverClassName("database.driver");
      dataSource.setUrl("database url");
      dataSource.setUsername( "tutorialuser" );
      dataSource.setPassword( "tutorialmy5ql" );
      return dataSource;
   }

  /**
   * Create the entity manager factory bean used in the database connection
   * @return entityManagerFactoryBean
   */
  @Primary
  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
    lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(portalJpaVendorAdapter());
    lef.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
    lef.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties);
    lef.setPersistenceUnitName("my_pu");
    return lef;
  }

  /**
   * Create the session factory bean
   * @return sessionFactoryBean
   */
  @Bean
  public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    sessionBean.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
    sessionBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
    return sessionBean;
  }

  /**
   * Create the JPA Vendor adaptor bean that is used in the entity manager factory
   * @return jpaVendorAdaptor
   */
  @Primary
  @Bean
  public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
    return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
  }

  /**
   * Create the transaction manager bean 
   * @return transactionManager
   */
  @Primary
  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    manager.setEntityManagerFactory(portalEntityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return new JpaTransactionManager();
  }
}
```

If you already have a datasource bean created you can autowire it instead of creating the bean directly.

Comment: Thank you, but this is a workaround and not a solution to the actual problem. If I need to do this, I will (and thanks for the code), but I really want to understand why it's not working as-is.